# How to listen to a module-native-protocol-tcp [mpd] pulseaudio tcp stream on two output devices with independent volume control

Tags: linux, networking, audio, pulse-audio, pipewire

I saw https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611158/how-do-i-monitor-microphone-input but this only applies to the mic apparently.

| (how do i create this list in markdow?) |
| --- |
| ✓ server: mpd pulseaudo plugin outputting stream to ip of client |
| ✓ client: 'pactl load.module module-native-protocol-tcp' |
| ✓ client: audio playback on specified output device, "JBL Xtreme 2" |
| ✓ client: `pavucontrol` displays "**Music Player Daemon**: Remote Pulse on" |
| ⍻ client: play mpd stream on "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (BAAS) with independent volume control |

I can create a monitor/loopback of the Bluez output device and play that on the BAAS speakers, but if I want to turn the JBL bluetooth speaker down and the BAAS speakers up, I can't.

```
$ pactl unload-module module-loopback; pactl load-module module-loopback source=module-native-protocol-tcp name=mtpt; pactl load-module module-loopback source=536870913; pactl list short|grep 53687
536870917
536870915
536870912   module-always-sink      
536870913   module-native-protocol-tcp      
536870915   module-loopback source=536870913    
536870917   module-loopback source=module-native-protocol-tcp name=mtpt
```

I see two loopbacks on pavucontrol, one of them outputs my mic to either of the speaker options, the other doesn't do anything.

How can I get the input tcp pulse stream to split into two streams I can output to multiple devices and adjust volume separately?

```
$ pipewire --version; pactl --version; uname -a
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 0.3.48
Linked with libpipewire 0.3.48
pactl 15.99.1
Compiled with libpulse 15.99.0
Linked with libpulse 15.99.0
Linux latitude 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```